# How to debug in PyCharm with Docker and multiple project dependancies

Tags: docker, pycharm

I have a python project A that depends on python project B.
Projects A and B can be edited in PyCharm.
I can launch a remote interpreter with Docker and docker-compose pycharm (pro) plugin and the breakpoints work well in all files in project A, but enven if the code in project B is run, I can't reach any breakpoint in B and I have this warning message in the logs:

> pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does
> not exist: /opt/project/c:/workspace/git...

What is the correct approach to debug both project A and B running docker-compose interpreter without copying project B inside project A in the host? (the solution can have one image by project or both projects in the same image)

Note that at the moment, both project A and B are in the same image (I use docker-compose to set up the database), and I have a bind mount like this:

> `/Project B/project_b_package:/opt/project/project_b_package`